# Ever-running timed tasks

Tags: concurrency, time

I need to design a piece of software which is invoking some actions regularly. By regularly I mean that there is x things that need to be done at 12.00, y things at 12.30 etc,etc.

The times and dates are accessible from the DB.

My question is - what would be the best approach to handling never-stopping nature of the app?

Obvious solution would be an infinite cycle with a timer and state of the app recording. If process dies, we start off the last entry. It is important that even if process dies when it's time to do something, we still do it when it has been restarted.

Are there any smarter approaches to this?

Would Ruby's [Class: Concurrent::TimerTask](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/concurrent-ruby/Concurrent/TimerTask) be of any real advantage as a timing mechanism (aside of being multi-threaded)?

Comment: Why would you not use a time-proven solution like `cron` or its variants? BTW see how [`anacron` handles the problem of resurrecting after a few tasks are late due to downtime](http://linux.die.net/man/8/anacron).

Comment: I'm asking about big application architecture, not some localhost - served perl script.

Comment: How big your application needs to be? E.g. does it need to be distributed (since you don't seem to be satisfied by running it on 'localhost')?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the case. If one triggering node dies, other has to step in and recognize the state of the application.

Comment: Airbnb seems to have what I need - https://mesos.github.io/chronos/
Still interested in answers on how to approach it without ready solutions, though.

Comment: Do you need more than one triggering node to run _simultaneously?_ If not, you're back to a localhost-based solution on top of fail-over + master-election logic. I suppose a database replicated between the triggering hosts would suffice to keep the state; anything from etcd to Cassandra could work. Mesos guys reuse the Mesos services to achieve that.

Comment: @kaboom, do you understand that every piece of software literally runs on localhost?

Comment: @sqadette I meant running software not in production environment. I'm well aware of way Linux works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to be careful with this kind of distributed system. For example: imagine I have a triggering server in London and another in New York. If a Deep One cuts through the cable between them, London will think "NY's gone down, I have to take over", and NY will think "London's gone done, I have to take over"... and your application will be triggered twice. That means you have to have at least 3 servers so one can act as a monitor for the others to arbitrate whether they are disconnected from each other or really down.

Often in such situations, one acts as a master and the other a standby, so only one is effectively running at any given time. When the standby detects the master is not longer responding (to heartbeats for example) then it becomes the master and takes over.

This supposes your application to be triggered is similarly distributed - no good London trying to run an app on the NY server if the NY server has failed.

Of course,it also supposes your DB is accessible from both servers, failure to contact the DB makes the currently running master server consider itself disconnected and intentionally fall over, and that means your DB has to be resilient too (or you might as well run your triggering server on the DB server itself).

Fully fault tolerant, distributed systems are not trivial to get right. You can get 80% of the required service quite easily, its the other 20% that's really hard. ZeroMQ has some great [architectural documentation](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#toc86) concerning network topology that is very good to read and will help you understand which type of fault tolerance you might want.

Given that, maybe all you really need is a localhost-served perl script that runs regularly and remembers the last time it ran. How long can you tolerate between the time something should run and when it does? If that time is greater than the reboot time of a server, there's your simple-yet-effective solution. IF you need absolute sub-second responses with 99.9999% availability - well, lets say the author of ZeroMQ probably still has a large hole behind his house that could yet be turned into an executive swimming pool.